# R - Auto fill columns in a dataframe from a range of dates

Tags: r

I have employee absence data as a data frame in the following format:

```
EmpID   Name   LeaveFrom    LeaveTo
xz123   ABC    07/12/2016   07/08/2016
kp546   PQR    06/28/2016   07/02/2016    
xz123   ABC    07/25/2016   07/27/2016
```

An employee may have more than one row assigned to him/her.

I would like to create a DF which reflects the above in the following format:

```
EMPID    Name  Jul-01  Jul-02 Jul03 ..Jul07 Jul08....Jul25  Jul26 Jul27 .Jul 31

xz123    ABC    P       P      P ...  A      A          A      A     A     P
kp546    PQR    A       A      P      P      P          P      P     P     P
```

Where P stands for Presence and A for absence.

Any idea how this could be done. I have around 30000 records

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: There should be an automated script to detect absence of code/user effort in resolving the issue and post the above as first comment!

Comment: The only way I know was to loop for each row. Which I think is not the most elegant of ways. I am looking for directions to avoid looping through each row

Comment: At least include your current best attempt so that SO users can comment/improve your solution, the links in the first comment could be helpful to ensure more responses for your query

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- read.table(text = "EmpID   Name   LeaveFrom    LeaveTo
    xz123   ABC    07/12/2016   07/18/2016
    kp546   PQR    06/28/2016   07/02/2016    
    xz123   ABC    07/25/2016   07/27/2016", header = TRUE)

## Convert is to date format first
df$LeaveFrom <- as.Date(df$LeaveFrom, "%m/%d/%Y")
df$LeaveTo <- as.Date(df$LeaveTo, "%m/%d/%Y")

## get sequence of dates to use
dates <- seq(min(df$LeaveFrom), max(df$LeaveTo), by = 1)
present <- rep("P", length(dates))

## apply the following function for every EmpID
resList <- lapply(split(df, df$EmpID), function(x){
    ## You need reshape2 packages to do this
    ## If you don't have it, you can install it: install.packages("reshape2")

    mL <- melt(x, id.vars = c("EmpID", "Name"))

    ## Number of rows is equal to the number of breaks
    ## It should be equal to number of times a given EmpID appears in df
    ## first column is the date at which the break began and second column is the date at which the break ended
    ## Instead of using dates, I convert them to indices of "dates" vector defined above
    m <- matrix(match(mL$value, dates), ncol = 2)

    ## make a vector of dates (indices) when an employee was absent
    absent <- unlist(apply(m, 1, function(x){
        x[1]:x[2]
    }))

    ## mark absent
    present[absent] <- "A"
    return(present)
})

df.final <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", resList))

## change date format to make it easier to read
colnames(df.final) <- format(dates, "%m/%d")
print(df.final)

##       06/28 06/29 06/30 07/01 07/02 07/03 07/04 07/05 07/06 07/07 07/08 07/09 07/10 07/11 07/12 07/13 07/14 07/15 07/16 07/17 07/18 07/19 07/20 07/21 07/22 07/23 07/24 07/25 07/26 07/27
## kp546     A     A     A     A     A     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P
## xz123     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     A     A     A     A     A     A     A     P     P     P     P     P     P     A     A     A
```